# I keep getting CSRF Token mismtach error (Cake\Network\Exception\InvalidCsrfTokenException) in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, web, cakephp-3.0, csrf

In CakePHP 3.5 I keep getting CSRF Token mismatch error (Cake\Network\Exception\InvalidCsrfTokenException) although csrf token in form and cookie are of same value. I have inspected the data submitted by my form and it also is successfully posting the data to target url.

Here is the code of my form :

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create().
$this->Form->control('email').
$this->Form->control('username').
$this->Form->control('password').
$this->Form->button('Register').
$this->Form->end();?>
```

My LoginController code :

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\View\Helper;
use Cake\View\View;

class LoginController extends AppController {   
 public function index () {
    $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('default');
 }  
}    
?>
```

Here is the error. [image]

Comment: Have you dumped out the values of `$request` to make sure the token is in there?

Comment: Yes I have and the token was same as in cookie and hidden field of form

Comment: Have you tried clearing all your cookies? Laravel has similar middleware, and sometimes if you're working on `dev.example.com` and `example.com` the cookies from dev and prod can conflict.

Comment: My hostname is localhost and I have tried cleaning only the csrf cookie and then all cokies of the browser. Even tried it with chrome.